# How to cite a French thesis in an international journal?

Tags: citations, cross-referencing

What is the right way to cite a French thesis in an international journal like Biomedical Signal Processing and Control? Should I convert the name of the university and the school to the English language?

Example:

> Aina Frau Pascual, Statistical models for the analysis of ASL and BOLD
>   Magnetic Resonance modalities to study brain function and disease,
>   Ph.D. thesis, Doctoral School of Mathematics, Information Sciences and
>   Technologies, Computer Science, GRENOBLE University (2016).

Link to the French thesis: http://www.theses.fr/2016GREAM086.pdf

Answer (score 4):

A bibliographical item should allow people to find the referenced work. This means that you should *at least* report the original title. Alongside the original title, you can add a translation, usually enclosed in brackets (this is not an issue for the thesis of interest because it's written in English). Other elements, like the university name, *should not* be translated, and you probably don't need to report the school name (but this depends on the bibliographical style).

Thus, I would cite that thesis as follows:

> Aina Frau Pascual, *Statistical models for the analysis of ASL and BOLD
>   Magnetic Resonance modalities to study brain function and disease*,
>   PhD thesis, Université Grenoble Alpes (2016).

Comment: Also some styles may have you point out that it is a thesis/dissertation.

Comment: The doctoral school certainly doesn't need to be in the citation. It is barely involved with the completion of the PhD. At best they're the ones who awarded you the PhD grant. In most cases they're nothing but an umpteenth administrative hurdle (other than formally allowing you to register each year and forcing you to take some... "classes", they're basically not involved).